# ps -vxa doesn't sort regarding to memory

Tags: freebsd, ps

The [FreeBSD manpage to `ps`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ps(1)) says:

> ```
> -v   Display information associated with the following keywords: pid,
>      state, time, sl, re, pagein, vsz, rss, lim, tsiz, %cpu, %mem, and
>      command.  The -v option implies the -m option.
> ```

yet it simply doesn't seem to work like this. `-m` is supposed to sort by memory usage:

> ```
> -m   Sort by memory usage, instead of the combination of controlling
>      terminal and process ID.
> ```

But this is a partial output of `ps -vxa`:

```
 PID STAT    TIME  SL  RE PAGEIN     VSZ    RSS LIM TSIZ  %CPU %MEM COMMAND
 ...
 871 Is   0:00.04 127 127     10   75620   7704   -  400   0.0  0.1 /usr/lo
1043 S    0:03.18   0 127   9599 1656244 253048   -  172   0.0  3.1 /usr/lo
1046 S    0:09.48   0 127    412 1672996 264060   -  172   0.0  3.3 /usr/lo
 873 I    0:00.14 127 127    123   65956  11432   -  280   0.0  0.1 /usr/lo
```

So, what happened here? Where is the sorting like we would assume from the description of `-m`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the results.  It is properly sorting for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sorting is right there.

The problem is that you are expecting it to sort on a single visible field when sorting by "memory usage".  It's badly documented, but the "memory usage" that is being sorted by is an invisible, and indeed unprintable, field that is the total of the `dsiz`, `ssiz`, and `tsiz` fields.